# Why is Jenkins pipeline returning -@tmp/durable-56090643/script.sh 4: FSUM7728 bad ${} modifier for shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I have this stage in my Jenkins pipeline that runs a command and stores the output in a variable. I'm trying to get the id number from the stored string but getting the error `bad ${} modifier`. Should have printed 00062100. It works correctly in the console.

```
  stage('test') {
   agent {node 'test'}
    steps{
        sh "string=$(onetstat -a -P 1111)"
        sh "echo ${string:6:8}"
    }
  }
```

output from the command("BUILD 00062100 Listen")

```
**Update:**    
stage('server2') {
   agent {node 'test'}
    steps{
            sh '''
                var="$(onetstat -a -P 1111)"
                echo ${var:6:8}
            '''
    }
  }

 **log of the run**
  [Pipeline] sh
    + + onetstat -a -P 1111 
    + 1<TMP> /tmp/shGgcEdAGgA 
 var=
 BUILDER8 00069B50 Listen  
 Local Socket:   127.0.0.1..1111                                     
 Foreign Socket: 0.0.0.0..0                                           
 /Build@tmp/durable-a93a2921/script.sh 3: FSUM7728 bad ${} modifier
```

Comment: `${var:start:len}` is a an extension. It's not POSIX-defined, and `sh` is not guaranteed to support any functionality that isn't defined in the POSIX sh specification.

Answer (score 3):

There are two misunderstandings in your example. When you use double quotes in the Jenkinsfile, you construct a [Groovy String](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/documentation/#_double_quoted_string) that substitutes variables (defined using `$` sign) with associated values (or expressions.)

Another misunderstanding is creating a bash variable in one `sh` step and accessing it in another `sh` step. It won't work that way. Each `sh` step runs in its own shell process, and any local variable created in one shell cannot be accessed in another.

You can solve both issues. Firstly, you need to replace double quotes with single quotes in `sh` step. Secondly, you need to define shell script in a single `sh` step. You can use Groovy multiline string for that (triple quotes.) Consider the following example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                // Below code prints nothing
                sh 'something="BUILD 00062100 Listen"'
                sh 'echo ${something:6:8}'

                // Below code prints 00062100
                sh '''
                    something="BUILD 00062100 Listen"
                    echo ${something:6:8}
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ something='BUILD 00062100 Listen'
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo

[Pipeline] sh
+ something='BUILD 00062100 Listen'
+ echo 00062100
00062100
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Tried the solution above but getting the same error.Updated the pipeline script I'm using and the log from the run. Thanks!

Comment: Used this solution to get the id from the command output                                                                                  var=$(onetstat -a -P 1111)
var=$(echo $var | cut -b 6-10)

Comment: @Szymon, ...this is all correct as far as it goes, but `/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to support `${var:start:length}` at all. I suspect that you tested this on a platform where `sh` is provided by bash, and the OP is operating somewhere it's provided by ash or dash.

Answer (score 0):

Used this solution to get the id from the command output

```
 var=$(onetstat -a -P 1111) 
 var=$(echo $var | cut -b 6-10)
```

Comment: This is buggy. Change `echo $var` to `echo "$var"`, or better, to `printf '%s\n' "$var"`. As it is, if `var='*'`, you'll end up with output containing the first few characters of a filename.

Comment: no value returned for var if I use "$var". Using output of a command here int his example not working with the file.                                                                                         var= 
+ echo

Comment: `var=$(echo "$var" | cut -b 6-10)` **absolutely** works. See it running in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/3HIMmv

Comment: This is the output if using "$var". Need the complete ID(00070A81) for this pipeline test.                                                                                                                            var=P NETS
Conn  
----  
00070A
ocket:
 Socke 
+ echo P NETS Conn ---- 00070A ocket: Socke 
P NETS Conn ---- 00070A ocket: Socke

Comment: Comments are not suited for the purpose -- the ideone link I gave above is useful because it preserves formatting; right now, there's no knowing what was originally a space and what was a newline. You might do something similar for your own examples. (If you're looking for a good ad-free generic pastebin, see https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: That said, this sounds to me like you're relying on the unquoted `$var` use to destroy whitespace in order for your (6-10) offsets to be correct. Better is to add the quotes, and fix the offsets.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  The basic idea is using cut is short answer to get a substring.

Comment: ...of course, unless I have the *real* data as it actually exists byte-for-byte, a lot of the above is necessarily going to be speculation; if you're only pasting in how things are shown by `echo`, that doesn't tell me their true byte-for-byte contents. `printf '%s=%q\n' var "$var"` prints the true value of `$var` in bash (with only printable characters, escaping carriage returns to `$'\r'`, newlines to `$'\n'`, and so forth), but it doesn't work with generic `/bin/sh`.